# Finding specific parts of strings containing certain letters/symbols and then creating a reference to those parts

Tags: c#, json, database, unity-game-engine

Currently I am storing data in form of jsons (strings) on a database. As jsons contain quotation marks though and the database I am using is unable to store quotation marks in this form: "  it converts all quotation marks (like this one :") to `&quot;`

Unity will therefor not allow me to deserialize the json anymore as it now looks somewhat like this:

```
{&quot;coins&quot;:0,&quot;level&quot;:0,&quot;kills&quot;:0,&quot;deaths&quot;:0,&quot;xp&quot;:0.0}
```

instead of like this:

```
{"coins":0,"level":0,"kills":0,"deaths":0,"xp":0.0}
```

Obviously a possible solution to this would be to find all the parts of my json string containing `&quot;`, storing a reference to these parts and then converting all of those parts to a simple "

Therefore I would ask you how I would go about doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `String.replace("&quot;","\"")` and than `String.split`, but maybe you need to think about moving to a database that supports JSONs, like mongodb. Other direction to solve this: have you tried placing the " as \"?

Comment: how would replacing a " with a \" help as surely that still contains a quotation mark?

Answer (score 1):

The Database is doing a good job by encoding the text for you thereby preventing Hacks!! It is simply doing text encoding for you.

All you have to do is Decode the text before using it. If there are chances that double quote is part of the data then you should be careful while reverse converting the encoded text. Refer to this MSDN resource [Anti-Cross Site Scripting Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973813.aspx) to get better insight into topic